# How do I store an input into a variable in HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am making a game that says a random number to click and then it tells you when it is right or wrong. I want the user to decide how many rounds they want and input it into the program.

```js
//takes the number of rounds and puts it into a variable so it shows the amount of questions you want
 var numberOfRounds = parseInt( document.getElementById( "numberOfRounds" ).value ) //puts the input numberOfRounds in a variable.
 console.log(numberOfRounds);
 randomNumber = ( Math.floor(Math.random() * 6));
 console.log(randomNumber);
 buttonColors();
```

```html
<font size="6"><center><strong><p id="startScreen">Welcome to the Random Color Game.</p></strong></center></font>
<font size="4"><center><p id="startScreen2">How many many rounds of the game would you like?</p>
<form id="numberOfRounds"><p id="startScreen3">I would like <input id="numberOfRounds" type="number" min="1" max="20" name="numberOfRounds" style = "width:100px; height:50px;"> rounds.</p>
<p id="startScreen5">To start playing the game, push begin.</p></center></font>
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are asking, also your html appears to be incomplete. Also what is the buttonColors function and what does it do?

Comment: `document.getElementById( "numberOfRounds" )` gives you the first  element found, i.e. `form`. That doesn't have value though. `id`s must be unique within the document.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is more-or-less correct -  `document.getElementById("numberOfRounds").value` will get the value from the `input` element, assuming that's the only element with `id="numberOfRounds"` (`id`s should be unique in the document).

I've refactored your code a bit and added a "Begin" button, which gets the value from the `<input>` element and displays it to the user.

```js
//puts the input numberOfRounds in a variable.
function getNumberOfRounds() {
  var setNumberOfRoundsElement = document.getElementById("setNumberOfRounds");
  var myNumberOfRoundsElement = document.getElementById("myNumberOfRounds");
  var numberOfRounds = parseInt(setNumberOfRoundsElement.value);
  myNumberOfRoundsElement.innerHTML = "You chose " + numberOfRounds + " rounds!";
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to the Random Color Game.</h1>
<div id="myNumberOfRounds">
  How many many rounds of the game would you like?
  <p>
    I would like
    <input id="setNumberOfRounds" type="number" min="1" max="20" name="numberOfRounds"> 
    rounds.
  </p>
  To start playing the game, push begin.
  <p>
    <button onclick="getNumberOfRounds()">Begin</button>
  </p>
</div>
```